# Change sharepoint database in the same machine

Tags: sql

I installed  sql server 2012 on  windows server 2008 R2 and sharepoint server 2013 stand alone, but there was sql server 2008 r2 on the server and it seems that my sharepoint database installed on that by default!
how can I move that to sql 2012 in the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

**Pre-Requisites**

- You must be a member of the Farm Administrators SharePoint group.
- You must be a member of the Administrators group.
- On the database server you must be a member `db_backupoperator` fixed database role and `db_owner` fixed database role

**Steps**

1. Close all open SharePoint Management Shell windows.
2. Stop all services that are related to SharePoint 2013 and Internet Information Services (IIS).
3. Detach the databases from the current SQL Server instance.
4. Copy or move all files that are associated with the databases (.mdf, .ndf, and .ldf), to the new destination server that runs SQL Server.
5. Make sure that all of the SQL Server logins, fixed server roles, fixed database roles, and permissions for the databases are configured correctly on the new destination database server.
6. Attach the databases to the new destination server that runs SQL Server.
7. Use SQL Server connection aliases to point to the new database server and update all web servers.
8. Start all services

Details for each step can be found in link https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725.aspx